# undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass when trying to upload file into database using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i am new to both ruby on rails and stackoverflow, so i hope i am doing this right.

i am trying to write a form to upload files into database using rails and i am getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ConfsController#create
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass: INSERT INTO "confs
("control_unit_brand", "control_unit_model", "created_at", "description", "developer_id",
"linear_axis_number", "machine_brand", "machine_model", "milling_mode",
"rotary_axis_number", "tool_axis_x", "tool_axis_y", "tool_axis_z", "turning_mode",
"updated_at", "user_id", "xml") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

this is request and i think it looks well:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"2OLwcjq/92i4VyZvO5/0SuTosuiTzbNQtVgk+cxmPQY=",
"conf"=>{"machine_brand"=>"mbrand3",
"machine_model"=>"mmodel3",
"control_unit_brand"=>"cbrand3",
"control_unit_model"=>"cmodel3",
"tool_axis_x"=>"10",
"tool_axis_y"=>"10",
"tool_axis_z"=>"10",
"rotary_axis_number"=>"3",
"linear_axis_number"=>"3",
"turning_mode"=>"t",
"milling_mode"=>"t",
"description"=>"desc",
"xml"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f067099d180
@original_filename="deneme.xml",
@content_type="text/xml",
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"conf[xml]\"; filename=\"deneme.xm
\"\r\nContent-Type: text/xml\r\n",
@tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20130821-3666-1c0gsxu>>},
"commit"=>"Upload"}
```

this is my whole new.html.erb file:

```
<% provide(:title, 'New Configuration')%>
<h1> Upload new configuration </h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">

<%= form_for (@conf, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :machine_brand %>
    <%= f.text_field :machine_brand %>

    <%= f.label :machine_model %>
    <%= f.text_field :machine_model %>

    <%= f.label :control_unit_brand %>
    <%= f.text_field :control_unit_brand %>

    <%= f.label :control_unit_model %>
    <%= f.text_field :control_unit_model %>

    <%= f.label :tool_axis_x %>
    <%= f.text_field :tool_axis_x %>

    <%= f.label :tool_axis_y %>
    <%= f.text_field :tool_axis_y %>

    <%= f.label :tool_axis_z %>
    <%= f.text_field :tool_axis_z %>

    <%= f.label :rotary_axis_number %>
    <%= f.text_field :rotary_axis_number %>

    <%= f.label :linear_axis_number %>
    <%= f.text_field :linear_axis_number %>

    <%= f.label :turning_mode %>
    <%= f.text_field :turning_mode %>

    <%= f.label :milling_mode %>
    <%= f.text_field :milling_mode %>

    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>

    <%= f.label :xml %>
    <%= f.file_field :xml %>

    <%= f.submit "Upload", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

i think the problem is about create function and here it is:

```
def create

@conf = Conf.new(params[:conf])

  if @conf.save
    flash[:success] = "New Configuration uploaded!"
    redirect_to @conf
  else
    flash[:error] = "There is a problem!"
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

this is from routes.rb :

```
match '/conf_new', to:'confs#new'
match '/conf_show', to:'confs#index'
resources :confs
```

i have tried lots of ways and could not figure it out what is wrong. i tried to restart server, even restart computer :), lots of advices and codes from internet, but all failed.

**edit**: my conf model:

```
class Conf < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :linear_axis_number, :control_unit_brand, :control_unit_model, 
:description, :developer_id, :machine_brand, :machine_model, :milling_mode, 
:rotary_axis_number, :tool_axis_x, :tool_axis_y, :tool_axis_z, :turning_mode, :user_id, 
:xml 

belongs_to :developer, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'developer_id'
belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
end
```

ok i solved this problem. in create i changed redirect_to @conf  to  redirect_to conf_show_path and this error is no more

Comment: Could you post your Conf model please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is not multipart, which it should be to upload a file. Use it like this:-

```
<%=form_for (@conf, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
```

Comment: i added multipart as you said, but now i cannot see even form and get this error: 
app/views/confs/new.html.erb:10: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...uffer.append=  form_for (@conf, :multipart => true) do |f| @...
and also this:
app/views/confs/new.html.erb:55: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end
but i have enough ends at the end

Comment: just added 1 more error, rest are same as before
error: /app/views/confs/new.html.erb:10: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
...url => confs_url, :multipart => true) do |f| @output_buffer....

Comment: last error changed, previous 2 are same. this is new error:
app/views/confs/new.html.erb:10: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
... :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| @output_buffer.safe_c...

Comment: This is a problem with braces/end mismatch. Check it throughly

Comment: i edited my new.html.erb file (which has the form) and put here whole file. it has only 1 form and 1 end. how can it mismatch?

Comment: Can you just post the files in question.

Comment: i didnt understand do you want file here?

Comment: Yeah put your files, so that we can figure out what is wrong with brances/end

Comment: it doesnt fit here, has too many characters. i can edit at the end of main question as you want, but it is already in main question and this would be repeating

Comment: If you revert the code (what we have done till now) it works?

Comment: it returns to the beginnig if i delete your code parts, dont say anything about end or syntax error. returns to the undefined method when submit form

Comment: I have to look into the files and figure out the issue. Is there any way you can send them or share them.

Comment: i couldnt find any email button on this site, maybe you can give me an email adress?

Comment: developer.vineet@gmail.com

Comment: i sent it, dont forget to check

Comment: nothing is changed, just like at the beginning, i think you just changed the form_for line but i was already tried it and it is still not working. maybe i should write the full error:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ConfsController#create
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass: INSERT

Comment: INTO "confs" ("control_unit_brand", "control_unit_model", "created_at", "description", "developer_id", "linear_axis_number", "machine_brand", "machine_model", "milling_mode", "rotary_axis_number", "tool_axis_x", "tool_axis_y", "tool_axis_z", "turning_mode", "updated_at", "user_id", "xml") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Rails.root: /home/staj/rails_projects/sample_app
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/confs_controller.rb:32:in `create'

by the way, line 32 is @conf.save, error points this

Answer (score 0):

You can try [attachment_fu](https://github.com/technoweenie/attachment_fu). It supports uploading in many ways.

Comment: last authored 5 years ago